# C# Datagrid has extra redundant column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image]I have a strange problem while trying to use Datagrids in C# . An extra column is appened to my datagrid which does not look neat .

I followed the tutorials that i always do [DataGrid in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/)  . I also downloaded the example and executed them but as i see in this example as well an extra column is appended . ( Figure 2 & Figure 7 )

Why is this so ? can i get rid of this redundant column ?

Left Panel :

```
    <DockPanel >
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Unsecured Devices" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="unSecure" ItemsSource="{Binding UnsecuredDevices}"/>
    </DockPanel>
```

Right Panel :

```
    <DockPanel  Grid.Column="2">
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Secured Devices" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="Secure" ItemsSource="{Binding SecuredDevices}" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: @IsmetAlkan yes but i did not write code according to it . I first wrote my own code and then searched online and realised this guy also has an extra column padding . Strange .

Comment: does he do padding? i couldn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not an empty column its just empty space left over, You can fix this by setting the `ColumnWidth` on your DataGrids

> **Auto** The unit of measure is based on the size of the cells and the column header.
>
> **Pixel** The unit of measure is expressed in pixels.
>
> **SizeToCells** The unit of measure is based on the size of the cells.
>
> **SizeToHeader** The unit of measure is based on the size of the column header.
>
> **Star** The unit of measure is a weighted proportion of the available space.

I think Star(*) will work for your layout `<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*">`

Answer (score 2):

set `ColumnWidth ="*"` Space is unused space of datagrid. you need to set column width to fill the space.

```
<DockPanel >
   <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Unsecured Devices" IsReadOnly="True"/>
   <DataGrid ColumnWidth ="*" x:Name="unSecure" ItemsSource="{Binding UnsecuredDevices}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Your previous answer centered the stuff . In a way it did solve the problem . Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial itself has an extra column as you said. You can adjust height and width, just for saving the day. Such as:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Secure" ItemsSource="{Binding SecuredDevices}" 
          Height="200" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,21,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" RowHeight="30" ColumnWidth="100" />
```